# Can I get my bounty reputation back by awarding it to myself?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

If I were to set a bounty on a question, could I then answer that question and award myself the bounty to regain that reputation? If that answer was purely to regain that reputation that could be a problem. This is a purely theoretical question and I am not thinking of doing it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't earn back your own bounty.  This is covered at [meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18841/lost-reputation-after-answering-my-own-question-with-bounty).

My favorite explanation is an analogy:

> It's a non-refundable plane ticket. You paid for one (50 of your own
>   rep), the system will throw in a free seat (the other 50 rep points).
>
> If nobody turns up with a valid passport (in this case, an answer with
>   at least 2 upvotes), the plane will still take off. Just that nobody
>   will be in those seats.
>
> You can take the seat yourself (answer and accept your own question),
>   but you're still not getting the refund.